# jquery read table values to count duplicated rows

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have some script to read the values from html table but there is a problem to compare name of existing items in array with temporary item name.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selling = new Array();
    $('table tr').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html();
        var price = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html();
        var amount = 1;
        var item = new Array(name,price,amount);
        var found = 0; //selling.find(name)? notworking :)
        if(found.length > 0) {
            alert('found'); //get amount and change it
        } else {
            selling.push(item); //push new item to array                       
        }
    });
    alert(selling);
});
```

I want to get an array

```
[cat, 10$, 150]
[cow, 120$, 7]
[bird, 500$, 1]
[horse, 400$, 2]
```

Can somebody tell me how to compare those names? or do this better way?

Comment: this is duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543514/check-whether-an-array-exists-in-an-array-of-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selling = new Array();
    $('table tr').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html();
        var price = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html();
        var amount = 1;
        var item = new Array(name,price,amount);
        if($.inArray(item,selling) > -1) {
            alert('found'); //get amount and change it
        } else {
            selling.push(item); //push new item to array                       
        }
    });
    alert(selling);
});
```