# javascript: Fast way to find connected components in array (looking for speed up / alternative way)

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, algorithm, matrix

I have an matrix (**1d array, x&y-axe**) like this:

```
var matrix=[
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111',
'11111100000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111',
'00000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000011',
'11111000000000000000000000000000000000000001111110000000000000000000000000001',
'11111000000000000111000000000000000000111111000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000000000111111111111100000000000000111111000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000000000000000110000000000000000000111111000000000000000000010000000000000',
'00000000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000',
'00000010010000000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000',
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000'
]
```

and I'D like to find all connected groups of '1'-characters and extract all of their positions to get something like this as result:

```
[{"0": [[68,0],[69,0],[70,0],[71,0],[72,0],[73,0],[73,1],[74,1],[75,1],[75,2],[76,2],[76,3],[76,1],[76,0],[75,0],[74,0]],"1": [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1]],"2": [[28,1]],"3": [[34,2]],"4": [[0,3],[0,4],[1,4],[2,4],[3,4],[4,4],[4,3],[3,3],[2,3],[1,3]],"5": [[43,3],[43,4],[43,5],[43,6],[42,6],[42,5],[42,4],[41,4],[41,5],[41,6],[40,6],[40,5],[40,4],[39,4],[39,5],[39,6],[38,6],[38,5],[38,4],[44,3],[45,3],[46,3],[47,3],[48,3]],"6": [[17,4],[17,5],[17,6],[18,6],[18,5],[19,5],[20,5],[21,5],[22,5],[23,5],[19,4],[18,4],[16,5],[15,5],[14,5],[13,5],[12,5],[11,5]],"7": [[63,6]],"8": [[31,7],[32,7],[33,7],[34,7],[35,7],[36,7],[37,7]],"9": [[5,8]],"10": [[66,8]],"11": [[6,9]],"12": [[9,9]],"13": [[38,9],[39,9],[40,9],[41,9],[42,9],[43,9],[44,9],[45,9]],"14": [[62,11]],"15": [[53,12]]}]
```

---

I have already developed some kind of a **[flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)** that is working quiet well with the matrix above.

> But there must be a way more efficient & fast way to find connected components in a bigger matrix (e.g 10 or even 100 times bigger).
>   --> My idea was maybe this result could be also achieved with some kind of **regex expression combined with javascript code**, but I'm absolutely not sure how to code this, so I hope somebody has an good idea to **fast up my little algorithm** below so that I can **avoid Overflow Errors** :

```js
var matrix=[
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111',
'11111100000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111',
'00000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000011',
'11111000000000000000000000000000000000000001111110000000000000000000000000001',
'11111000000000000111000000000000000000111111000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000000000111111111111100000000000000111111000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000000000000000110000000000000000000111111000000000000000000010000000000000',
'00000000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000',
'00000010010000000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000',
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000'
]

Array.prototype.extract_components_positions = function(offset) {
 var array = this.map(item => item.split('')).map(str => Array.from(str, Number)),
  default_value = 0,
  result_object = {}

 function test_connection(array, i, j) {
  if (array[i] && array[i][j] === -1) {
   if (!result_object[default_value]) result_object[default_value] = [];
   result_object[default_value].push([j, i]);
   array[i][j] = 1;
   for (var k = offset; k > 0; k--) {
    test_connection(array, i + k, j); // left - right
    test_connection(array, i, j + k); // top - bottom
    test_connection(array, i - k, j); // right - left
    test_connection(array, i, j - k); // bottom - top
   }
   return true
  }
 }
 array.forEach(function(a) {
  a.forEach(function(b, i, bb) {
   bb[i] = -b
  })
 });
 array.forEach(function(a, i, aa) {
  a.forEach(function(b, j, bb) {
   test_connection(aa, i, j) && default_value++
  })
 })
 return [result_object];
}



var result = matrix.extract_components_positions(1);
console.log((result))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

> Edit 1.0 BTW It would be also not that bad if the algorithm is just able to connect bigger components *(e.g minimum group of 5 connected characters)*

Comment: You might want to take a look at [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html). There's also an entire [article on matrices by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Matrix_math_for_the_web)

Comment: Can not even find one matching information to my question. Just some less important information about other kinds of matrixes. Not really helpful @ctxwheels

Comment: Well since no one else was able to help I figured I'd try. If that's not helpful I do apologize, but both links I provided include matrix math in JavaScript. I figured *maybe* one of them might be of use to you.

Comment: Should we decode output? Where are explanations?

Comment: Just (x/y) positions in an object, should be easy to see @revo

Comment: Your implementation of the recursive version you linked to seems pretty good to me. Further down that link is a mention about scanline fill (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Scanline_fill) being more efficient. Perhaps you could look up some algorithms / pseudocode for that.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

This is the method I figured out. I'm sure it can be optimized, but I feel it's at least a big step in the right direction.

I've also taken information from the following answers and applied it.

- [Finding all indexes of a specified character within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10710437/3600709)
- [Check whether an array exists in an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33210887/3600709)

```js
var matrix=[
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111',
'11111100000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111',
'00000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000011',
'11111000000000000000000000000000000000000001111110000000000000000000000000001',
'11111000000000000111000000000000000000111111000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000000000111111111111100000000000000111111000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000000000000000110000000000000000000111111000000000000000000010000000000000',
'00000000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000',
'00000010010000000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000',
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000'
]

var results = [];

function charPos(str, char) {
  return str
         .split("")
         .map(function (c, i) { if (c == char) return i; })
         .filter(function (v) { return v >= 0; });
}

matrix.forEach(function(s, i) {
  var p = charPos(s, '1');
  results[i] = [];
  matrix.forEach(function(s2, i2) {
    var p2;
    if((p2 = charPos(s2, '1').filter((n) => p.includes(n))).length) {
      p2.forEach(function(v) {
        if(JSON.stringify(results).indexOf(JSON.stringify([v, i2])) === -1)
          results[i].push([v, i2]);
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log(results.filter(v => v.length > 0));
```

Comment: Are you sure this output matches OP's one?

Comment: @revo I know it doesn't, but from the specifications of the question itself, it does match. It gets an array of positions where the first match is returned based on the index of the string in the matrix, setting priority on the lowest array items such that if a match is found in array item 0 and array item 2, the match is reported in array item 0.

Comment: @revo If I'm misunderstanding this question, then I can delete my answer, I just feel like this might help the OP or someone else design a better method for the OP to resolve their problem. I'm sure with some minor tweaks that the OP's result can be achieved with my above methods.

Comment: By _connected_ the querist means adjacent in a 2-dimensional grid as it appears in the source matrix of columns and lines. So, for example the `1` at position `[28,1]` is not connected to the cluster `[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1]`.