# Remove array from array of arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, filter

I want delete array from array of arrays without iterate on them.

the first array is like this :

```
array1 = [ 
[
[{"id":"A1","y":12},{"id":"A4","y":12}],
[{"id":"A2","y":1}], 
[{"id":"A3","y":6}]  
]
```

the second array is :

```
array2 = [{"id":"A1","y":12},{"id":"A4","y":12}]
```

I use javascript and i want delete array2 from array1.

So sorry for wrong description by the way i found that in my exemple the second array array is

```
array2 = [{ "id": "A1", "y": 12 }, { "id": "A4", "y": 2 }]
```

So the two arrays have just one columns which is equal. How i can delete array1 from array2 even they have just one attribute which is equal ?

Thank you.

Comment: `Array.filter`. `Array.includes`

Comment: `array1` is wrong, there is an extra `[`

Comment: Are the `id's` unique?

Comment: id is not unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feels weird, but you can check every element of the array and match to the second array. Either way you need to iterate through your array. You can't simply type `array1[i] == array2`, you need to check it differently. A hack is to stringify them as JSON and compare strings, but there are [other methods you can use to compare arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript/14853974).

Here is a simple demo with a for loop

```js
array1 = [
  [{ "id": "A1", "y": 12 }, { "id": "A4", "y": 12 }],
  [{ "id": "A2", "y": 1 }],
  [{ "id": "A3", "y": 6 }]
]
array2 = [{ "id": "A1", "y": 12 }, { "id": "A4", "y": 12 }]
l = array1.length
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  // if arrays match
  if (JSON.stringify(array1[i]) == JSON.stringify(array2)) {
    // delete the element at `i` position
    array1.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
    l--;
    // break; // if you can guarantee that no more instances will occur 
  }
}
console.log(array1)
```

Comment: i found that in my exemple the second array array is 

array2 = [{ "id": "A1", "y": 12 }, { "id": "A4", "y": 2 }]

So the two arrays have just one columns which is equal.

How i can delete array1 from array2 even they have just one attribute which is equal ?

Answer (score 2):

**splice** is usually used to remove a particular item from the array. I think you want to do something like this:

```
    var array = [

        [{"name": "sik", "gender": "male"}],
        [{"name": "sug", "gender": "female"}],
        [{"name": "hyd", "gender": "male"}]

    ];

    // it removes the second array from the array: removes the female one.
    array.splice( 1, 1 );
```

**Description:** The function splice takes two arguments, first one is for the index of item, and second one until how much you want to delete.

**For Example:** splice( 2, 5 ) - means that: from the index **2**, keep deleting until **5** items.

Hope this helps, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Plain Javascript, we cannot filter them. This will work if u are dealing with valued datatypes. Here you are comparing arrays which are a referenced datatype. so here we need to write our own search stack

```
function searchForArray(haystack, needle){
var i, j, current;
for(i = 0; i < haystack.length; ++i){
if(needle.length === haystack[i].length){
  current = haystack[i];
  for(j = 0; j < needle.length && needle[j] === current[j]; ++j);
  if(j === needle.length)
    return i;
}
}
return -1;
}

var arr = [[1,3],[1,2]];
var n   = [1,3];

console.log(searchForArray(arr,n));
```

You can refer this question which has some reference resources too.
[Check whether an array exists in an array of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543514/check-whether-an-array-exists-in-an-array-of-arrays)

I know you asked for a solution without iteration, but i just thought to give an idea of references which may be useful for u.