# How to check that array contain array (of numbers)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates

I stored several coordinate pairs in a single array.
For example:

```
[[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]]
```

I'd like to find the coordinate pair that I got.
I got coordinate:

```
[4,5]
```

If array contains this coordinates that I'll get true otherwise false.
This is my code:

```js
function isContain(coords) {
   for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if (array[i].length !== coords.length) return false;

       for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
           if(array[i][j] === coords[j]) {
               return true
           }
       } 
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(array).includes(JSON.stringify())`

Comment: See also [Check whether an array exists in an array of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19543514/215552)

Comment: Thank you, my problem sloved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
const foo = [[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]];
const coords = [4, 5];

function isContain(coords) {
  for (const f of foo) {
    if (f[0] === coords[0] && f[1] === coords[1]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(isContain(coords));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the coordinates always contains exactly two items, you don't need the inner loop, just compare the Xs and the Ys directly. Also use `for...of`:

```
function isContain(coords){
  for(let item of array) {
    if(item[0] == coords[0] && item[1] == coords[1]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

You can also use `some` instead like so:

```
let exists = array.some(item => item[0] == coords[0] && item[1] == coords[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply comparing numbers you could do convert to strings:

```
const isContain = coords =>
{
   for (let item of array)
   {
      if (item.split("") === coords.split(""))
         return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
arr.some(e=> e==''+[4,5])
```

```js
let a=[[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]]

let isContain = (arr) => arr.some(e=> e==''+[4,5]);

console.log( isContain(a) );
```