# Using .includes to find sub-array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, include

I have an element i want to search for in the format of [numOne, numTwo]. i want to be able to search through an array called movesTaken two find this element.

lets assume this:

```
let numOne = 0;
let numTwo = 1;

let movesTaken = [[0,1],[5,8],[3,2],[4,7],[8,3],[9,8],[5,4],[1,1],[4,4],[3,9],[1,43],[23,6]];
```

what i've tried to do is achieve a true or false value by using .includes() by using the below code

```
movesTaken.includes([numOne,numTwo]);
```

and ive also tried

```
movesTaken.includes([0,1]);
```

neither of these options seem to work and only output false, how would i go about testing if these exist in the array? will this leave me with no choice but to use a for loop to loop through each individual sub-array and their individual values?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54901676/5648954) answer from the duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

I think you can use something like this

```js
let array = [0, 1];
let movesTaken = [[0,1],[5,8],[3,2],[4,7],[8,3],[9,8],[5,4],[1,1],[4,4],[3,9],[1,43],[23,6]];
let check = movesTaken.some(a => array.every((v, i) => v === a[i]));

console.log(check);
```