# Javascript find nested array in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I have an array

```
a = [ [1,2],[3,4] ]

b = [1,2]
```

I want to find if b is in a, how would i do that?

I tried using

```
a.includes(b) 

or

a.find(e => e == b)
```

but both don't work

Comment: in the find you can try using `JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify(b)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543514/check-whether-an-array-exists-in-an-array-of-arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over `a` with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). If the length of the inner array doesn't match the length of `b` immediately return false, otherwise use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check that the inner array [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) all of the elements of `b`. This will also check when elements are out of order like `[2, 1]` should you need to do so.

```js
const a = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] ];
const b = [ 1, 2 ];
const c = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
const d = [ 3 ];
const e = [ 3, 4 ];
const f = [ 2, 1 ];

function check(a, b) {
  return a.some(arr => {
    if (arr.length !== b.length) return false;
    return b.every(el => arr.includes(el));
  });
}

console.log(check(a, b));
console.log(check(a, c));
console.log(check(a, d));
console.log(check(a, e));
console.log(check(a, f));
```